# C++ ask user for file name, if they enter nothing how do i correctly re-prompt

Tags: c++, string, is-empty

creating a program that will prompt user until the given file exist, so far if the file exist it re-prompts them. but when i prompt the user for a file name, and they decide to press enter all i get is white space until i enter characters. how would it be possible to re-promt when user decides to enter nothing.

```
  while(fileName.empty())/*********************/
            {
            cout<<"Enter file name: ";
            cin>> fileName;
            }
```

### ^attempt of re-prompting when given an empty string^

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        string line;
        ifstream inData;
        ofstream outData;
        string fileName = " ";
        char digit;
        float num[1000];
        float sum[10];
        int num_count;
        int  i = 0;
        float user_num,tot,result;


/*Program will ask user for file name, read the file
sum the first 3 numbers of the file, then will prompt
the user for a fourth number in which it will sum all
numbers and print the average*/


        while(fileName.empty())/*********************/
        {
        cout<<"Enter file name: ";
        cin>> fileName;
        }

        inData.open(fileName.c_str());
        /*outData.open(fileName.c_str());*/

        while(!inData.is_open())
        {
        cout<<"Please enter a valid file name or path: ";
        cin>>fileName;
        inData.open(fileName.c_str());
        }


        if (inData.is_open())
         {
            while (inData.good())
            {
                inData >> digit;
                num[i] = digit - '0';
                i++;
                num_count = i - 1;
            }
        inData.close();



        cout<<"Enter fourth number: ";
        cin>> user_num;
        num[3] = user_num;


        for(int a = 0; a <= 3; a++)
        {
            tot += num[a];
        }


        result = tot/4.0;

        cout<<"The average of the four numbers is: "<<result<<'\n';

        }

        return 0;
}
```

here is my test file

jim.txt

```
2 44 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use getline instead of operator<< like this;

```
while (fileName.empty())
{
  cout << "Enter file name: ";
  char c[255];
  cin.getline(c, 255);
  fileName = string(c);
}
```

ps: Just noticed comment from  @DawidPi with the same suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop with checking emptiness will not be executed (even a single time) as you initialized `fileName` with `" "` (so it's **not empty**). Use `do...while()` or simply do not initialize `std::string` (there is no need for it.)

Comment: even when i do not initialize the filename to " ", it is still stuck and doesn't re-promt until a char is typed

Comment: try using `getline()` function with `std::cin` instead of `>>` operator.